# Uploaded file only contains "WebKitFormBoundary"

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I don't really know what's going on here. Every time I try to upload a file, all the file contains is:

`------WebKitFormBoundaryJ0uWMNv89fcUsC1t--`

I have searched for the past 2 days for some sort of explanation, but I am just going in circles. I have no idea why this is happening.

#### Form:

```
<form id="upload-file" ecntype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="picture" type="file">
    <input type="button" value="Upload" id="upload-button" />
</form>
```

#### Javascript:

```
$('#upload-button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($('#upload-file'));
        $.ajax({
            url: '/image',  
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {  
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(myXhr.upload){ 
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
           // contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
```

#### Controller:

```
def image = Action(parse.temporaryFile) { request =>
   request.body.moveTo(new File("/tmp/picture"))
   Ok("File uploaded")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was occuring in the Javascript, not the Scala. I was not referencing the form elements improperly.

```
var formData = new FormData($('#upload-file')[0]);
```

However, I also had problems with `parse.temporaryFile` and it was not properly storing the file using the code above. When I inspected the stored files in a text editor, I noticed it still had the `------WebKitFormBoundaryJ0uWMNv89fcUsC1t--` stuff at the beginning of the file, followed by the form information, then followed by the file bytes.

To fix this, I just used the default method for multipartform upload as per the [Play Documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaFileUpload), and it worked perfectly.

```
def image = Action(parse.multipartFormData)  { request =>
   request.body.file("picture").map { picture =>
      val filename = picture.filename
      picture.ref.moveTo(new File(s"/tmp/picture/$filename"))
      Ok("ok")
   }.getOrElse {
      InternalServerError("file upload error")
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, too. I did not even think about doing it as in the doc they say that you have to use parse.temporaryFile when uploading with Ajax.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaFileUpload#Direct-file-upload