# Dropzone JS Upload to WCF Getting Wrong Data

Tags: javascript, c#, image, wcf

First of all, I'm new to both WCF services and dropzone JS, but I'm trying to combine the two to create a simple image uploader.  I've got my WCF working correctly for the metadata that I've uploaded to through it (so I know it's passing things cross domain correctly), but the Stream that I've captured from Dropzone doesn't match the image that I dropped. In fact, every single image dropped results in the same encoded string server-side ...

For example, I've used this [star image](http://images.clipartpanda.com/clipart-star-RTA9RqzTL.png) as a test, and by uploading the image to a [base64 online converter](https://www.base64-image.de/), I can see that the beginning of the base64 string looks like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOYAAADbCAMAAABOUB36AAAAwFBMVEX...
```

However, when I debug my WCF code, the base64 converted string looks like this:

```
LS0tLS0tV2ViS2l0Rm9ybUJvdW5kYXJ5T1RUV0I1RFZZdTVlM2NTNQ0KQ29udG...
```

**This string above is the same one for created for every image that I try to send.**

So now for all the applicable code pieces.  I've got a simple webpage in one project and the WCF related files in another project in the same solution.

Index.html:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <form action="http://localhost:39194/ImageRESTService.svc/AddImageStream/"
            class="dropzone"
            id="dropzone"></form>
</div>
...
Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
        maxFilesize: 10, // MB
    };
```

OperationContract:

```
/*  Stores a new image in the repository  */
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                UriTemplate = "AddImageStream/")]
    void AddImageStream(Stream img);
```

AddImageStream implementation:

```
public void AddImageStream(Stream img)
    {
        //try to save image to database  
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
        int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
        string encodedData = "";

        do
        {
            bytesRead = img.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            encodedData = encodedData + Convert.ToBase64String(buffer,
                                       Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        } while (bytesRead > 0);
}
```

Webconfig applicable pieces:

```
<services>
  <service name="ImageRESTService.ImageRESTService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="ImageRESTService.IImageRESTService" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147000000" />
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
<bindings>

  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" name="ImagesBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
    <binding name="webHttpBinding" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="10485760" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="1000000" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

The problem is visible when I break on the encodedString piece and it doesn't match what I'm expecting. If I copy the entire string into another online image that generates images from base64 strings, it's not a valid image.  At this point I'm stuck and haven't been able to determine why I can't read from dropzone.

Comment: Just check what data your browser sends and you will see if it is client or server problem.

Comment: Chrome shows the correct string representing the jpeg being sent in the network tab.

Breaking in the WCF service on the variable encodedData shows that same string for every image.  This isn't the first variable serverside, I should probably be checking the value of the Stream variable for the AddImageStream function, but I'm not sure how to see a value there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking to configure a WCF service to catch dropzone images, be aware that dropzone sends multipart/form-data that looks like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="DSCF0001.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<file bytes>
------WebKitFormBoundary--
```

There isn't a built-in way to parse this data that I found, however this [blog post](http://antscode.blogspot.ca/2009/11/parsing-multipart-form-data-in-wcf.html) goes into more details and provides a [codeplex MultipartParser class](http://multipartparser.codeplex.com/) that worked perfectly for this scenario.

Simplified WCF code now looks like:

```
public string AddImageStream(Stream img)
    {
        MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(img);

        string encodedString = "";

        if (parser.Success)
        {
            // Save the file
            encodedString = SaveFile(parser.Filename, parser.ContentType, parser.FileContents);
        }

        return encodedString;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I decode your received base64 string `LS0tLS0tV2ViS2l0Rm9ybUJvdW5kYXJ5T1RUV0I1RFZZdTVlM2NTNQ0KQ29udG`

I get

`------WebKitFormBoundaryOTTWB5DVYu5e3cS5
Cont`

So I guess that you have a problem in referencing element like in this post:
[Uploaded file only contains "WebKitFormBoundary"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769832/uploaded-file-only-contains-webkitformboundary)

Comment: This was just the hint I needed to figure out what was going on with the data being wrapped by the "WebKitFormBoundary..." wrapper.

Comment: Sorry Jehy, didn't realize I could award the bounty without accepting your answer and I wanted to lay it out in more details for anyone else finding this.  Appreciate it.